# C++ Class Templates unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, header-files, template-classes

I have the following in a header file. A template class with many functions.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;    

template <class T>
class Vector3Generic
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;

    Vector3Generic();
    ~Vector3Generic();
    Vector3Generic(T vx, T vy, T vz);
    Vector3Generic(Vector3Generic& v);
    // 
    // ... many functions, some static, and some are not.
    static T Vector3Generic::Distance(const Vector3Generic& a, const Vector3Generic& b);
    static T Vector3Generic::Slope(const Vector3Generic& linepoint1, const Vector3Generic& linepoint2);

};      
template <class T>
T Vector3Generic<T>::Distance(const Vector3Generic<T>& a, const Vector3Generic<T>& b)
{
    auto vector = Vector3Generic<T>(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
    return sqrt(((vector.x * vector.x) + (vector.y * vector.y)) + (vector.z * vector.z));
}
template <class T>
T Vector3Generic<T>::Slope(const Vector3Generic<T>& linepoint1, const Vector3Generic<T>& linepoint2)
{
    return (linepoint2.z - linepoint1.z) / (linepoint2.x - linepoint1.x);
}
```

My problem is that I only get the error message for the included functions above. I cannot figure out the problem.

Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: do not qualify member functions' names with `Vector3Generic::` within class scope

Comment: why even split them, just implement the templates inside the class

Comment: @CaptainObvlious no code is using this class yet. Why is that relevant?

Comment: @PiotrS. It worked! But why is that? I have around 20 functions and only these two complained. For all other I still use Vector3Generic:: for the names and it compiles fine.

Comment: @AramAzhari what compiler?

Comment: @PiotrS.MsVC++ (Visual Studio 2013)

Comment: @AramAzhari I can't tell without code, are those other "working" methods static as well? are you actually using them in the code?

Comment: These are some that work:


   
 `template <class T>
    Vector3Generic<T> Vector3Generic<T>::Normalized() const
    {
 T num = Vector3Generic<T>::Magnitude();
 if (num > 1E-05f)
 {
  return (*this / num);
 }
 return Vector3Generic<T>::Zero();
    }`

I haven't started using them. I had a float class implementation and I wanted to make it work with double and int.

If I actually write the implementation in a separate cpp file, then I have to put the Vector3:: on the function names or it won't compile (for a non-template implementation)

Comment: @PiotrS.In fact if I remove the Vector3Generic:: from other function names I get "modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions"